# Qt Drag and drop between two QTableView objects

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm using pyqt6. I have two QTableView objects. I'd like the user to drag rows from one table and drop them into another table. Behind the scenes, what I want is to link the data in a one-many relationship. So, if the user drags row1 from table B and drops in row2 in tableA, I will create an fk relationship in my database like tableB.row1 -> tableA.row2 (This should be irrelevant to the question, I just put it in order to give more context). Is this possible? If so, could you give me links to useful resources?

Clearing:
I would like to track when a user drags a row from Table X and drops it onto row j in Table Y. In this scenario, I need to execute code that establishes a link between them in the background. Specifically, I want the foreign key field in Table Y to contain the corresponding primary key value from Table X.

Comment: It's unclear what should be the effect of the drag and drop, since you say that what you do is irrelevant to the question. Should the source row be inserted? Or its data copied? Are you asking how to get some notification when a user drops an item from another table? Then, just override `dropEvent()`. In any case, read the documentation about [drag and drop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) and that related to [model views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views).